# How to make this line of php into a function?

Tags: php, function

I have a navigation, where I echo out the class based on the variable on the page.

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="<?php echo ($page == 'home' ? 'active' : 'inactive'); ?>" class="nav-active"><a href="/" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
   <li class="<?php echo ($page == 'home' ? 'active' : 'inactive'); ?>" class="nav-active"><a href="/" title="Another Page Page">Another Page</a></li>

</ul>
```

I am new to PHP and I'm trying to figure out how I' would make it into a function so I can just called it and add the arguments.

```
<li class="<php activeNav($page, $current); ?>">
```

Can someone explain how to do this? And sorry for not giving a very descriptive title, don't know what to call it.

Comment: need `?` before `php` so its `<?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why this would improve your code, but you can try this:

PHP:

```
function activeNav($page, $current) {
    return ($page == $current) ? "active" : "inactive";
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="<?php echo activeNav($page, 'home'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Level 1

```
function activeClass( $page, $current = 'index') {
    if( $page == $current){
         return ' active';
    }
    return ' inactive';
}
```

Usage:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="nav-active<?php echo activeNav( 'home', $page); ?>"><a href="/" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
   <li class="nav-active<?php echo activeNav( 'another', $page); ?>"><a href="/" title="Another Page Page">Another Page</a></li>                  
</ul>
```

#### Level 2

```
function printNavigationElement( $page, $title, $current = 'index'){
    $title = htmlspecialchars( $title);
    return '<li class="nav-active' . activePage( $page, $current) . '"><a href="/' . htmlspecialchars($page) .
        '" title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
}
```

Usage:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <?php
    echo printNavigationElement( 'home', 'Home page', $page);
    echo printNavigationElement( 'another', 'Another page', $page);
?>
</ul>
```

#### Level 3 - [oop](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

```
class NavigationItem {
    public $url;
    public $title;

    public function __construct( $url, $title){
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}

class Navigation {
    // You should use setters and getters with protected variables
    public $current = '';
    public $items = array()

    public function display() {
        echo '<ul class="nav">';
        foreach( $this->items as $item){
            printNavigationElement( $item->url, $item->title, $this->current);
        }
        echo '</ul>'
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php

$navigation = new Navigation();
$navigation->current = $page;
$navigation->items[] = new NavigationItem( 'home', 'Home page');
$navigation->items[] = new NavigationItem( 'another', 'Another page');
$navigation->display();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$page` is the current page and `$current` the type of page you want to check against, you could do:

```
function activeNav($page, $current) {
    $class = ($page == $current) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    return $class;
}

<li class="<?php echo activeNav('home', 'home'); ?> nav-active"><a href="/" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
```